# Is it possible to export a file while inside a docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Inside my docker image I am creating a FBX file. After the file is finished processing I want to export to my local machine. I want to do this from docker image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run your container as this:

```
docker run -v $(PWD)/local-dir/:/path/to/results/dir (...rest of the command..)
```

So any file that is created inside the container into `/path/to/results/dir` gets automatically reflected in your host, inside `./local-dir`.

---

Alternatively, you can copy any file from container to host:

```
docker cp <container-id>:/path/to/file ./local-dir
```

Comment: I tried --- docker run -ti -v $(pwd)/Users/kromah/Documents/Developer/Github/Unity/unity-pipeline-maya:/root/workdir dock -- I got 
Waiting for Xvfb..., but the file did not output into the folder

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
docker cp <container_id:your/file/inside> <file/outside>
```

additional [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)

Comment: This command cannot be run inside of docker image. I get a docker command not found

Comment: You run this from the **host**!

Comment: I need to run it from inside the image

Comment: Why?!?! That is a pretty significant restriction, which you did not specify in your post.

Comment: @Robert alludes to it in his post, so he understood, but I have edited the question.